# unsupervised post-training in neural network

Tags: neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I have done a lot of research in terms of neural networks - especially convolutional neural networks. My Network produces a linear output using the identity function. After several trainings, the MSE was bounded to a minimum.

After having a closer look into the results, I found out, that the MSE per subject differs per training. I.e. Net 1 is doing good work on person 1 and 2, but not so good on person 3 and 4. Net 2 which is trained using the exact same training dataset gets the same MSE, but is doing better on person 3/4 and worse on 1/2.

After this I came up with the idea of a unsupervised post training. There might be a correlation between person 1/2 and 3/4. Maybe a smaller head or what so ever. So I might switch the weights depending on what the learner tells me to use? Has anyone doen that before? Is there any literature?

Comment: Are persons 1, 2, 3, and 4 part of the training set, or are they test data?

Comment: They are from the test set, of course!

Comment: In that case, you might want to try adding some regularization to the model for training.  It's possible that it's overfitting the training data.  I'm not familiar with any literature with respect to your idea of unsupervised post training, but it wouldn't hurt to experiment.  Sorry, wish I had more advice to offer.

Comment: I do use weight decay and some dropConnect, so I think it doesnt overfit that hard. It was just an idea I came up with and I couldnt find any literature on it